# Type X is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<X>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am requesting few data from the server in my **PostService** :

```
getPosts(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get<Response>(this._url, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
```

and then I call this get function in my **CategoryPageComponent** :

```
export class CategoryPageComponent implements OnInit {

  data: Observable<Response>;
  public posts= [];
  status;
  errorMsg;
  isLoaded: boolean = false

  constructor(private _navbarService: PostService, ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategoryPosts();
  }

  getCategoryPosts() {
    this._navbarService.getPosts().subscribe(
      data => {
        if (!data) {
          console.log(Error)
        } else {

          //Error here
          this.data = data;

          console.log(data)
          this.posts = data.result.BlogPost
          console.log(this.posts)
        }
      }) 
  }
}
```

I want to bind data as loaded:

```
<div *ngIf="data | async">
      <h4>{{posts[0].Title}}</h4>
</div>
```

However, I get the following error for the following assignment in my component

```
this.data = data;
```

```
 Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Response>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign `this.data = this._navbarService.getPosts()`, instead you are assigning the received data.